# Measuring page load time urllib2 vs curl

Tags: python, curl, urllib2

Hello I am doing a project for school that investigates Apache's mod_deflate's effects on bandwidth and latency when web requests are served and am looking for suggestions on how to measure such load times.

I'm familiar with the phases of loading a web page and have decided that measuring the render time of a website is irrelevant to the metrics I want to test. My gap in understanding is why the time it takes to curl my website is much longer than that of using urllib2 to open my website.

Here's the Python code that I believe captures the time to transfer a webpage's static resources to a client.

```
site = urllib2.Request('http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx')
site = urllib2.urlopen(site)
st = time()
site = site.read()
et = time()
site.close()
print(et - st)
```

This code results in a time that is 2 order of magnitudes faster than

```
time curl http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Any suggestions or insight would is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` is doing much more. You're timing

1. Shell's startup of "curl" command.
2. curl connects with remote site
3. curl requests file
4. time to download file

`python` portion only tests

1. time to download.

You'd get a better comparison, if you move your `st = time()` to before your call to `urlopen(site)`.